# Angularfire2 shows "Missing permissions" error, whilst straight firebase runs with no issue

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire, firebase-security

AngularFire2 seems to handle permissions differently to pure firebase sdk.

Steps to reproduce this issue:

- Log in to a user account
- Make a call to retrieve the firestore document for the user:

```js
return this.afStore.doc('users/' + authId).valueChanges()
  .pipe(map(u => {
    if (u) {
      return new User(u);
    }
    return null;
  })
);
```

- Log out of that user account and then to log in to another user account
- Make the same call to retrieve the firestore document for the new user
- This time is returns a `Missing or insufficient permissions` error

If I add the code for firebase directly into my `index.html` file, it works though:

```js
var email = "xxx@xxx.com";
var password = "xxx";
var firebaseConfig = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((u) => {
  if (u) {
    firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + u.uid).get()
      .then(u => console.log("Got favorites", u.data()));
    firebase.firestore().doc('favorites/' + u.uid).get()
      .then(u => console.log("Got favorites", u.data()));
  }
});

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
  console.log("Signed in", cred)
})
```

My firebase rules are as follows, but they seem to be ok in the simulator and obviously work from the front end some of the time:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function internalGetUserFromReq() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
    }

    //...

    match /users/{userID} {
      allow read, write: if internalGetUserFromReq().data.authId == userID;
      allow read, write: if internalGetUserFromReq().data.role == 0;
    }
}
```

**FULL IMPLEMENTATION**

For a more full picture, here is my login method:

```js
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
  return this.user$;
}).catch((err: Error) => {
  this.logout();
  throw new Error(err.message);
});
```

I logout like this:

```js
return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
  this.appState.clean();
  return this.router.navigate(['']);
});
```

And I am listening to the Firebase AuthState like this:

```js
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => {
  if (user) {
    return this.getUser().pipe(catchError((err: Error) => {
      this.logout();
      return throwError(err);
    }));
  }
  return of(null);
})).pipe(share());
```

The `getUser()` method referenced in the switchMap is the original method I pasted in my question at the top, just returning an observable of the document that belongs to that user (e.g. `users/12345`).

**RECAP**

To recap the issue, the login/logout and AuthState observer all function as expected, but I when add firebase rules to my Firestore documents that would restrict the user to only access their own document (i.e. where `authID` matches `request.auth.uid`), then the document becomes inaccessible. This behaviour only occurs through the AngularFire2 package, and persists after the page is reloaded and even when opening the app in a brand new browser with clean cookies and cache.

**WORK AROUND**

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I have had to strip out `AngularFire2` (and same applies to the new `@angular/fire` package) and replace it with my own wrapper around the core `firebase` package.

**REPRODUCTION**

I am unable to create a reproduction at the moment - I know that's annoying and I will try to do one when I have more time. However, the issue is so deep rooted in AngularFire2 that I will have to create a fresh angular app, setup a new Firebase instance, complete with authentication, a Firestore database, and document access rules and then also implement a full user login journey. To do the issue justice, I would also need to setup the same again but without AngularFire2, just to prove that it is that package causing the issue. It's too much work for me to cram into my rare days off at the moment!

If anyone has time to tinker and wants to set one up, drop me a message and I will gladly help.

Comment: I have since experienced this issue on another completely separate project. I have had to create my own services around firebase and remove angularfire from my projects entirely, which solves the issue but is a lot of extra work when this is a basic feature that should work out the box.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] with the complete flow... the login function, what happens then? you fetch the user? also logout is missing from your code.

Comment: I will try to create one but its quite a niche and complex issue and requires me setting up firebase db with rules etc, as well as loading up an angular app so will take me some time to do all this. Not sure I will get time to do this for a few days... I was hoping someone else who has had the same issue might be able to help without me having to recreate the whole thing.

Comment: Note, logout I did not think is relevant here, hence I have not included it.

Comment: yeah, I understand making a demo would be difficult, but meant in this case that show all the code that produces this issue, therefore the logout (and login) would be relevant as well, since it's apparently part of the issue :) Seeing the flow, anyone could then try and replicate the issue. I for one, have a guess what it **could** be, but can't tell if I don't see the code ;)

Comment: how do you get `authId ` and what will happen to it when you logout. I guess your subscription is till alive and when you log in with another use it's still running under the old user context (you can log some data to check)

Comment: @RezaRahmati, nope I am handling the unsub, and even if I weren't the issue persists even after a page refresh. In fact, even after I clear cache and cookies, or open in a new browser, incognito, or any other completely fresh environment!

Comment: @AJT_82 I have added these parts of my code to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

when you log in you get the firebase auth user,you take its Id and then you subscribe to the user document from the database, probably you are using 2 subscription, one to the auth and the second to the user full document (we don't see the full authentication code here), now when you are logout out your user document subscription is still running but you don't have the premission to get the user full document now because you not loged in anymore (and the rules are about the auth user), my solution is to use switchMap with angularFire auth so there are only one subscription (this is actually kind of what you did in the later code - in the html only)

** your error is probably because of the logout and not the new login

```
private _sub: Subscription;

constructor(private _auth: AngularFireAuth, private _db: AngularFirestore){
     this._sub = this._auth.authState
        .pipe(
            switchMap(u => (u)
                ? this._db.collection('Users).doc(u.uid)
                    .valueChanges()
                : of(null))
        .subscribe(user => {
           // some actions
            });
}
```

Now when you logout firebase will not try to get the user document again and get this error

Comment: Unfortunately I am already using this method. I have added my login function to the question. This issue is not related to subscription management, as it persists after page reload.